# Release Management 2015 Update configuration variables during release

Tags: ms-release-management

I have created an "Agent-based Release Template" which has the release path SIT->RQA->PREPROD->PROD->DR.  We are currently waiting for Qa to signoff of the PREPROD release for a weekend publication to PROD.  When we started this release we did not know the value for some of the configuration variable in a component that will replace tokens in the web.config file, so we left them blank.  I have on previous version of release management been able to edit these values while a release is "in flight" for an environment that has not been released yet. Unfortunately I have not been able to edit the values for this release and I am unsure if that is by design or if the release needs to be in a specific state.  Does anyone know why I can't change the variables?

Comment: what version of release management are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's by design, I believe. Typically, when a value needs to change for a specific stage, you restart the entire release.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are seeing when you try to edit the configuration variables.

[image]

This is because you have tasks with the same name in that stage.
I would have recommended to edit the task names and keep them unique. But since you are using 'Agent Based Release Template' you are left with only one option.

You need to manually edit the configuration variable for each tasks of that stage. From my screenshot you can see that i am allowed to edit the configuration variable for Deploy using PS/DSC task.

For informational purpose, microsoft released an all new version of release management with TFS 2015 update 2. You might want to look at it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Release/overview